# Get multiple Items in a Custom ListView with checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a custom listView that load a TextView, an ImageView and a checkbox for each row.

To manage a single item I use

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                long x = MyClass.this.adapter.getItemId(position);
                            ......

            }
        });
```

That allow me to get the id x of a single clicked row, that I can use to retrieve the data associated with the single row.

Now:

How Could I get the various position index of all the clicked rows?

My ListAdapter is

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Activity activity;
    private String[] dataCar;
    private String[] dataImm;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public TitleLoader titleLoader;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    public TextLoader textLoader;

    public MyAdapter(Activity a, String[] dCar, String[] dImm) {
        activity = a;
        dataCar=dCar;
        dataImm=dImm;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        titleLoader=new TitleLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return dataImm.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista_car, null);

        TextView car=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.car);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        titleLoader.DisplayTitle(dataCar[position], car);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(dataImm[position], image);

        return vi;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the various position index of all the clicked rows?*

Comment: In my sample method there is a long x that get the position of one clicked item... I want to get an array with the positions of all clicked items in a multiple selection.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want from the itemId. Can you add the code of your adapter? From what I see you want to get the selected `CheckBoxes` from the `ListView`, right?

Comment: I have added the adapter... I want to get the positions of all clicked items.

Comment: If you want the **clicked** rows then simply use an array of boolean values as big as the `ListView`'s data size(dataImm.length) and when the user clicks a row simply change the value from that `boolean` array. When you want to know which rows were clicked just iterate over that array and see which positions are true(meaning row was clicked). Also in your code the method `getItemId(position)` is useless, simply use the position parameter.

Comment: Yes.... It's an easy solution... I cannot figure how is possible that I haven't think this before... Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Luksprog to fix the problems I have used an array of boolean.
When I click the various entry the respective positions became set to true. Using the index of true element in this array allow me to access all the checked rows of the list

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                long x = MezzoStampa.this.adapterListaTestate.getItemId(position);
                CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                cb.setChecked(true);
                if(cb.isChecked())
                    checked[(int)x]=true;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use `onListItemClick`
i am giving you an example

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent,View v,int position,long id){
    try{
        TextView t4=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        TextView t5=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Desc);


        if(t4!=null){
            EEActionListBean mSelected; // bean ur set get class
            int idx=position;//
            mSelected=m_adapter.getItem(idx); // this will give you position clicked

            String getvalueoflist=mSelected.getID();

                Intent intent=new Intent(this,EEActionListDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("sID",ActionID);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //MsgBox(this,e.toString());
    }
}
```